# Referencing other properties in {} object creation

Tags: javascript, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Self-references in object literal declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

How do I do the following:

```
var object = {
    alpha: 'one',
    beta: **alpha's value**
}
```

without splitting the object creation into two parts?

Comment: Hmm.. well that stinks.  I was trying to add enum types to my object like var object = { CURVETYPE: {DIRECT: 0, ROAD: 1}, travel: this.CURVETYPE.DIRECT }, but I can see this is going to ruin my nice namespace now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, object literal syntax just doesn't support this, you'll have to create a variable first then use it for both, like this:

```
var value = 'one';
var object = {
  alpha: value,
  beta: value
};
```

Or...something entirely different, but you can't reference `alpha` when doing `beta`, because neither property has been created yet, not until the object statement runs as a whole is either accessible.

Comment: .. I'm getting "o is undefined"

Comment: @BrunoLM - Nope: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/Gnbjq/ Again `o` is `undefined` when you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 7):

You can't, as noted.  The closest equivalent is:

```
var object = new (function()
{
    this.alpha = 'one';
    this.beta = this.alpha;
})();
```

This uses a singleton instance created from an anonymous function. You can also declare private fields with `var`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with `{}` object creation.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea for a way to create that object, without cluttering the scope with any new variables:

```
var lit = function(shared) {
return {
    alpha: shared.v1,
    beta: shared.v2,
    gamma: "three", 
    delta: shared.v1

};
}(
 {
    v1: "one",
    v2: "two",
 }
);
```

One of those statements you're not sure how to indent....