# Self-references in object literals / initializers

Tags: javascript, object-literal

Is there any way to get something like the following to work in JavaScript?

```
var foo = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    c: this.a + this.b  // Doesn't work
};
```

In the current form, this code obviously throws a reference error since `this` doesn't refer to `foo`. But *is* there any way to have values in an object literal's properties depend on other properties declared earlier?

Answer (score 1027, accepted):

Well, the only thing that I can tell you about are [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

```js
var foo = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
  get c() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
}

console.log(foo.c) // 11
```

This is a syntactic extension introduced by the ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification, the syntax is supported by most modern browsers (including IE9).

Comment: Very helpful answer. More info on 'get' can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get

Comment: Beware that with this solution if the values of `foo.a` or `foo.b` are changed then the value of `foo.c` will also change in synchronism. This may or may not be what is required.

Comment: @HBP That would be the exact same thing as what would happen in the question, so it seems to me like that is exactly what the expected result had to be.

Comment: Does the "function" `c` actually gets executed each time `foo.c` is dereferenced?

Comment: This looks functionally equivalent to: `... c: function() { return this.a + this.b; } ... foo.c()`, any gotchas with this assumption?

Comment: FYI getter functions do not allow parameters I believe -- does not apply to this case but I think that's one difference to be noted.

Comment: do you think it is possible to "imitate" getter features in es3? maybe a polify?

Comment: Also wanted to mention that if you assign the getter prop to another object, the result is evaluated, so you're not moving a function, where the `this` binding can be lost, but also means you're not moving the "getter", you're evaluating the getter and then copying the result.

Comment: Note that `this` binds to the deepest nested object. E.g.: `... x: { get c () { /*this is x, not foo*/ } } ...`

Comment: To complete my above statement, since `foo` is beeing declared as a variable and `c` will only be evaluated at the time it is invoked, using `foo` inside `c` will work, as opposed to `this` (be careful though)

Comment: If one wanted further optimization, one could also assign the `c` property in the getter, so that it's only calculated once, rather than on every access of `.c`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Yes, but you'll need to `delete` the getter first (within the getter) as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40498293/3579498). Key to note, if a property has a getter, you can only change its value after deleting the getter or using `Object.defineProperty`. If you're using a self-deleting (i.e. memoized) getter, later reassignment will fail if the property hasn't been accessed at least once.

Comment: also see the [binded closure example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literals-initializers/64628403#64628403) below

Answer (score 353):

You could do something like:

```
var foo = {
   a: 5,
   b: 6,
   init: function() {
       this.c = this.a + this.b;
       return this;
   }
}.init();
```

This would be some kind of one time initialization of the object.

Note that you are actually assigning the return value of `init()` to `foo`, therefore you have to `return this`.

Comment: you can also `delete this.init` before `return this` so that `foo` is not poluted

Comment: @BillyMoon: Yes indeed, although doing so [impacts performance](http://jsperf.com/test-dictionary-mode) of all subsequent property accesses on that object, on many engines (V8, for instance).

Comment: `this` in ES6 classes works as expected. So no need to call init there.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: Not sure how ES6 classes are relevant to the question.

Comment: @MuhammadUmer: classes are just syntactic sugar for constructor functions, so they don't really provide anything new. Either way, the main focus of this question are object literals.

Comment: why do you have to return this at the end?

Comment: @akantoword: I'm assigning the return value of `init` to `foo`, so I have to return the object itself.

Comment: @FelixKling but why do you have to return something though, even if you don't have that return statement, shouldn't the init function do it's job of creating 'c'? why does it have to have the return statement to work?

Comment: @akantoword: Remove the `return` statements and try it. Of course `c` is created, but because `init` doesn't return anything, `foo` will be `undefined`, so there is no way to use / access the object afterwards. Again: The return value of `init` is assigned to `foo`.

Comment: @FelixKling why is the return value of `init` assigned to `foo`? sorry if this is off topic, but it doesn't make sense to me that `init` has to return something because it's purpose is to create `c`. to me, `init` is just another property of `foo`, so when `foo` is defined with the object literal, it shouldn't be dependent on `init` to return itself. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something very basic here, but I don't know what.

Comment: @akantoword: In the last line, `init` is called immediately. If we omit what's inside the object literal, it would look like `var foo = { ... }.init();`. Is it clearer now why the return value of `init` is assigned to `foo`? We could also do this in multiple statements, then `init` wouldn't have to return anything: `var foo = { ... }; foo.init();`.

Comment: @FelixKling that made it much more clear, thank you! I didn't know it'd make a difference with 2 statements vs 1.

Comment: @akantoword: Great :) since object literals are a single expression,  the `init()` call was directly appended the literal to keep it a single expression. But of course you can call the function separately of you want to.

Comment: @tambre: Interesting. But of course, that's just V8, not other engines.

Comment: If others are still confused, its helpful to highlight the dot part of .init(), you are chaining this on to the definition. Actually a good way to see this is that when you run this, you get back whatever the last function on the line returns. See this perhaps as chained functions in jQuery, so you are chaining the definition of the object with the running of the init function. if the init function did not return anything, as mentioned previously you'd just get undefined.

Answer (score 228):

The obvious, simple answer is missing, so for completeness:

> But *is* there any way to have values in an object literal's properties depend on other properties declared earlier?

No. All of the solutions here defer it until after the object is created (in various ways) and then assign the third property. The *simplest* way is to just do this:

```
var foo = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6
};
foo.c = foo.a + foo.b;
```

All others are just more indirect ways to do the same thing. (Felix's is particularly clever, but requires creating and destroying a temporary function, adding complexity; and either leaves an extra property on the object or [if you `delete` that property] [impacts the performance](http://jsperf.com/test-dictionary-mode) of subsequent property accesses on that object.)

If you need it to all be within one expression, you can do that without the temporary property:

```
var foo = function(o) {
    o.c = o.a + o.b;
    return o;
}({a: 5, b: 6});
```

Or of course, if you need to do this more than once:

```
function buildFoo(a, b) {
    var o = {a: a, b: b};
    o.c = o.a + o.b;
    return o;
}
```

then where you need to use it:

```
var foo = buildFoo(5, 6);
```

Comment: For my own sanity, I'm trying to find some kinda of official documentation that says basically the same thing - that an object's `this` is only available to _methods_ of said object, and no other kinds of properties. Any idea where I could find that? Thanks!

Comment: @DavidKennell: Doesn't get more official than [the specification](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer). :-) You'd probably start [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) and follow it through. It's fairly awkard language, but basically you'll see in the various subclauses of [Property Definition Evaluation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-propertydefinitionevaluation) that the object isn't available to the operations determining the values of property initializers.

Comment: I can't see the [browserscope results here](https://jsperf.com/test-dictionary-mode), but this is no more the case right? In my environment, v8: `delete` is 10% faster and gecko : `delete` is  just 1% slower.

Comment: @TheMaster - Yeah, I don't think BrowserScope is really a thing anymore. Looks like deleting isn't as bad as it used to be, at least not in V8 (Chrome, etc.) or SpiderMonkey. Still slower, but only a tiny bit, and these things are freaky fast these days.

Answer (score 72):

Simply instantiate an anonymous function:

```
var foo = new function () {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 6;
    this.c = this.a + this.b;
};
```

Comment: @Bergi, why? Because someone might instantiate another of the same object from it? It's not like they can't just clone an object literal. It's no different than passing an argument like `new Point(x, y)` except that the function isn't named for reuse.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Of course they can just clone the object, but compared to an IEFE solution (like in TJCrowder's answer) your solution leaks the constructor function and creates a superfluous prototype object.

Comment: @Bergi, sure, but this is significantly more expressive.

Comment: @zzzzBov: Just use `var foo = function() { this.…; return this; }.call({});` which is syntactically not much different but semantically sane.

Comment: @Bergi, if you feel it's that important, why not add your own answer to the mix?

Comment: @zzzzBov I think it's just a variation of TJ's answer

Comment: You've got this. I indeed did not notice the `new` keyword.

Answer (score 42):

Now in ES6 you can create lazy cached properties. On first use the property evaluates once to become a normal static property. Result: The second time the math function overhead is skipped.

The magic is in the getter.

```
const foo = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
    get c() {
        delete this.c;
        return this.c = this.a + this.b
    }
};
```

In the arrow getter `this` picks up the [surrounding lexical scope](http://eddmann.com/posts/arrow-functions-lexical-this-scoping-in-javascript/).

```
foo     // {a: 5, b: 6}
foo.c   // 11
foo     // {a: 5, b: 6 , c: 11}
```

Comment: es5 also has properties you just need to use `Object.defineProperty(foo, 'c', {get:function() {...}})` to define them. This is easily done in an unobtrusive way in a factory such as this one. Of course if you can use the `get` sugar it is more readable but the capability has been there.

Comment: this works perfectly, but may I know why are you deleting this.c when it doesn't even exists ?
I tried without writing `delete this.c` but it didn't work

Comment: I was scratching my head about the `delete` as well. I think what it's doing is removing the `get c` property from the object and overwriting it with a standard property. I think this way it will only compute once and then `foo.c` will not update its values if `a` or `b` change later, but this also only works/caches/computes upon calling `foo.c`.

Comment: Yes this is what is called lazy evaluation. More here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation

Comment: The point of `delete this.c` is to remove the getter and then proceed to replace it with a single numeric value. Doing it this way avoids needing to execute the getter every time `foo.c` is used. The `return` statement both creates the replacement property `foo.c` and returns its value. It would be possible to use `get c() { return this.a + this + b }` but that would be re-evaluated every time `foo.c` is used.

Answer (score 27):

Some closure should deal with this;

```
var foo = function() {
    var a = 5;
    var b = 6;
    var c = a + b;

    return {
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c
    }
}();
```

All the variables declared within `foo` are private to `foo`, as you would expect with any function declaration and because they are all in scope, they all have access to each other without needing to refer to `this`, just as you would expect with a function.  The difference is that this function returns an object that exposes the private variables and assigns that object to `foo`.  In the end, you return just the interface you want to expose as an object with the `return {}` statement.

The function is then executed at the end with the `()` which causes the entire foo object to be evaluated, all the variables within instantiated and the return object added as properties of `foo()`.

Comment: It is confusing and misleading to call this a "closure". Although opinions differ on the precise meaning returning an ojbect value from a function does not constitute a closure in anyone's book.

Answer (score 18):

You could do it like this

```
var a, b
var foo = {
    a: a = 5,
    b: b = 6,
    c: a + b
}
```

That method has proven useful to me when I had to refer to the object that a function was originally declared on. The following is a minimal example of how I used it:

```
function createMyObject() {
    var count = 0, self
    return {
        a: self = {
            log: function() {
                console.log(count++)
                return self
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By defining self as the object that contains the print function you allow the function to refer to that object. This means you will not have to 'bind' the print function to an object if you need to pass it somewhere else.

If you would, instead, use `this` as illustrated below

```
function createMyObject() {
    var count = 0
    return {
        a: {
            log: function() {
                console.log(count++)
                return this
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then the following code will log 0, 1, 2 and then give an error

```
var o = createMyObject()
var log = o.a.log
o.a.log().log() // this refers to the o.a object so the chaining works
log().log() // this refers to the window object so the chaining fails!
```

By using the self method you guarantee that print will always return the same object regardless of the context in which the function is ran. The code above will run just fine and log 0, 1, 2 and 3 when using the self version of `createMyObject()`.

Answer (score 12):

For completion, in ES6 we've got classes (supported at the time of writing this only by latest browsers, but available in Babel, TypeScript and other transpilers)

```
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 6;
    this.c = this.a + this.b;
  }  
}

const foo = new Foo();
```

Answer (score 8):

just for the sake of thought - place object's properties out of a timeline:

```
var foo = {
    a: function(){return 5}(),
    b: function(){return 6}(),
    c: function(){return this.a + this.b}
}

console.log(foo.c())
```

*there are better answers above too*. This is how I modified example code you questioned with.

**UPDATE:**

```
var foo = {
    get a(){return 5},
    get b(){return 6},
    get c(){return this.a + this.b}
}
// console.log(foo.c);
```

Comment: In ES6 you can make this general approach much more elegant: `var foo = { get a(){return 5}, get b(){return 6}, get c(){return this.a + this.b} }` so now you can just do `foo.c` instead of `foo.c()` :)  (Feel free to paste that into your answer so formatting is better!)

Comment: Note that this recomputes `foo.c` every time it's used. This may or may not be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using the module pattern. Just like:

```
var foo = function() {
  var that = {};

  that.a = 7;
  that.b = 6;

  that.c = function() {
    return that.a + that.b;
  }

  return that;
};
var fooObject = foo();
fooObject.c(); //13
```

With this pattern you can instantiate several foo objects according to your need.

http://jsfiddle.net/jPNxY/1/

Comment: This isn't an example of the module pattern, just a function. If the last line of the foo definition was `}();`, it would self execute and return an object, not a function. Also, `foo.c` is a function, so writing to it clobbers that function and the next invocation via `fooObject.c()` will fail. Maybe this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awilliams47/3rbks/1/) is closer to what you're going for (it's also a singleton, not designed to be instantiated).

Comment: "The Module pattern was originally defined as a way to provide both private and public encapsulation for classes in conventional software engineering". From: [Learning JavaScript Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript).

That's object follow the module pattern described above but maybe it isn't the best one to explain that because is not showing public and private properties/methods.

This one http://jsfiddle.net/9nnR5/2/ is the same object with public and private properties/methods. So both of them are following this pattern

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to accomplish this; this is what I would use:

```
function Obj() {
 this.a = 5;
 this.b = this.a + 1;
 // return this; // commented out because this happens automatically
}

var o = new Obj();
o.b; // === 6
```

Comment: This works, but eliminates the advantages of the object literal notation.

Comment: True, sorry I missed the object-literal tag originally. I mostly only use object literals for data structures, and anytime I want any additional logic (which might resemble a class) I create the object as the result of a function for this very reason.

Answer (score 6):

The `get` property works great, and you can also use a binded closure for "expensive" functions that should only run once *(this only works with `var`, not with `const` or `let`)*

```js
var info = {
  address: (function() {
    return databaseLookup(this.id)
  }).bind(info)(),

  get fullName() {
    console.log('computing fullName...')
    return `${this.first} ${this.last}`
  },

  id: '555-22-9999',
  first: 'First',
  last: 'Last',
}

function databaseLookup() {
  console.log('fetching address from remote server (runs once)...')
  return Promise.resolve(`22 Main St, City, Country`)
}

// test
(async () => {
  console.log(info.fullName)
  console.log(info.fullName)
  console.log(await info.address)
  console.log(await info.address)
  console.log(await info.address)
  console.log(await info.address)
})()
```

Answer (score 6):

Just for everyone's amusement:

```js
var foo = (                        (This={
    a: 5,
    b: 6,                          })=>({...This,
    c: This.a + This.b             }))(
);

console.log(foo);
```

Comment: haha :-)...........

Comment: Interesting hack. You would need to add `var` or `let` in front of first `This` to make it work in strict mode.

Comment: @MikkoRantalainen No, `This` is a parameter (this isn't exactly obvious, I know). It doesn't need a preceding variable declaration keyword.

Comment: Oh, I originally read that code as using object initializer for defining `This` and as far as I know, those always require declaration in strict mode. However, as you correctly point out, that's actually function definition with arrow syntax and `This` is the function parameter that simply "happens" to have default value that matches an implicit object. I consider this as an yet another example where arrow functions reduce readability of JS code a lot because you have to do lots of backtracking to correctly parse the code.

Answer (score 5):

Creating new function on your object literal and invoking a constructor seems a radical departure from the original problem, and it's unnecessary.

You cannot reference a sibling property during object literal initialization.

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 2, c: a + b } // not defined 
var y = { a: 1, b: 2, c: y.a + y.b } // not defined
```

The simplest solution for computed properties follows (no heap, no functions, no constructor):

```
var x = { a: 1, b: 2 };

x.c = x.a + x.b; // apply computed property
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the following code as alternative, and it works. And the variable can be array too. (@ Fausto R.)

```
var foo = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
  c: function() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  },

  d: [10,20,30],
  e: function(x) {
    this.d.push(x);
    return this.d;
  }
};
foo.c(); // 11
foo.e(40); // foo.d = [10,20,30,40]
```

Answer (score 3):

The other answers posted here are better but here's an alternative that:

- Sets the value at initialization (not a getter, or derived, etc)
- Doesn't require any type of `init()` or code outside of the object literal
- Is an object literal and not a factory function or other object creation mechanic.
- Shouldn't have any performance impact (except at initialization)

**Self-executing anonymous functions and window storage**

```
var foo = {
    bar:(function(){
        window.temp = "qwert";
        return window.temp;
    })(),
    baz: window.temp
};
```

The order is [guaranteed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17438220/728393) (`bar` before `baz`).

It pollutes `window` of course, but I can't imagine someone writing a script that requires `window.temp` to be persistent. Maybe `tempMyApp` if you're paranoid.

It's also ugly but occasionally useful. An example is when you are using an API with rigid initialization conditions and don't feel like refactoring so the scoping is correct.

And it's dry, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of behavior of 'this' in the object.

```
this.prop = 'external';
global.prop = 'global.prop';
const that = this;

const a = {
  prop: 'internal',
  prop1: this.prop, //external

  log() {
    return this.prop //internal
  },
  log1: () => {
    return this.prop //external
  },
  log2: () => {
    return function () {
      return this.prop; //'global.prop' in node; 'external' in chrome
    }()
  },
  log3: function () {
    return (() => {
      return this.prop; //internal
    })()
  },
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The key to all this is **SCOPE**.

You need to encapsulate the "parent" (parent object) of the property you want to define as it's own instantiated object, and then you can make references to sibling properties using the key word `this`

It's very, very **important** to remember that if you refer to `this` without first so doing, then `this` will refer to the outer scope... which will be the `window` object.

```
var x = 9   //this is really window.x
var bar = {
  x: 1,
  y: 2,
  foo: new function(){
    this.a = 5, //assign value
    this.b = 6,
    this.c = this.a + this.b;  // 11
  },
  z: this.x   // 9 (not 1 as you might expect, b/c *this* refers `window` object)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

if your object is written as a function which returns an object, AND you use ES6 object-attribute 'methods', then it's possible:

```
const module = (state) => ({
  a: 1,
  oneThing() {
    state.b = state.b + this.a
  },
  anotherThing() {
    this.oneThing();
    state.c = state.b + this.a
  },
});

const store = {b: 10};
const root = module(store);

root.oneThing();
console.log(store);

root.anotherThing();
console.log(store);

console.log(root, Object.keys(root), root.prototype);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a neat ES6 way:

```js
var foo = (o => ({
    ...o,
    c: o.a + o.b
  }))({
    a: 5,
    b: 6
  });
  
console.log(foo);
```

I use it to do something like this:

```js
const constants = Object.freeze(
  (_ => ({
    ..._,
    flag_data: {
      [_.a_flag]: 'foo',
      [_.b_flag]: 'bar',
      [_.c_flag]: 'oof'
    }
  }))({
    a_flag: 5,
    b_flag: 6,
    c_flag: 7,
  })
);

console.log(constants.flag_data[constants.b_flag]);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this  solution this will work with nested objects with array as well

```
      Object.prototype.assignOwnProVal
     = function (to,from){ 
            function compose(obj,string){ 
                var parts = string.split('.'); 
                var newObj = obj[parts[0]]; 
                if(parts[1]){ 
                    parts.splice(0,1);
                    var newString = parts.join('.'); 
                    return compose(newObj,newString); 
                } 
                return newObj; 
            } 
            this[to] = compose(this,from);
     } 
     var obj = { name : 'Gaurav', temp : 
                  {id : [10,20], city:
                        {street:'Brunswick'}} } 
     obj.assignOwnProVal('street','temp.city.street'); 
     obj.assignOwnProVal('myid','temp.id.1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Throwing in an option since I didn't see this exact scenario covered.  If you *don't* want `c` updated when `a` or `b` update, then an ES6 IIFE works well.

```
var foo = ((a,b) => ({
    a,
    b,
    c: a + b
}))(a,b);
```

For my needs, I have an object that relates to an array which will end up being used in a loop, so I only want to calculate some common setup once, so this is what I have:

```
let processingState = ((indexOfSelectedTier) => ({
    selectedTier,
    indexOfSelectedTier,
    hasUpperTierSelection: tiers.slice(0,indexOfSelectedTier)
                         .some(t => pendingSelectedFiltersState[t.name]),
}))(tiers.indexOf(selectedTier));
```

Since I need to set a property for `indexOfSelectedTier` and I need to use that value when setting the `hasUpperTierSelection` property, I calculate that value first and pass it in as a param to the IIFE

Answer (score 1):

I think following is best code for maintanability even though it's not in object literal syntax:

```js
var foo = function() {
   this.a = 5;
   this.b = 6;
   this.c = this.a + this.b;
   return this;
}.call({});
```

This creates a new empty object with `{}` and then uses the anonymous function to set its properties (executed with `call()`). I think the only bad part is the need for `return this` which feels like one extra line of code. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out any nicer way to move the reference to newly created anonymous object to `foo`.

I think this is better than syntax `var foo = new function() {...}` because this one doesn't create one extra level in the prototype chain as explained by @Bergi in the comments in one of the existing answers.

However, if this is truly literal without any other logic but one addition, it would make more sense to just write

```js
const foo = {
    a:5,
    b:6,
    c:11, // sum of a + b
};
```

because there's no need to calculate that sum during runtime or even compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative syntax with pretty good maintanability:

```
let a = 5;
let b = 6;
let foo = {
  a,
  b,
  c: a+b,
};
```

This works because JavaScript will use the variable name as the property name for the newly created object if you don't specify the name explicitly. For a short array like this, I'd personally go with single line syntax with `return` if this were inside a function:

```
let a = 5;
let b = 6;
return { a, b, c:a+b };
```

Answer (score 0):

### Two lazy solutions

There are already excellent answers here and I'm no expert on this, but I am an expert in being lazy and to my expert eye these answers don't seem lazy enough.

#### First: return object from anonymous function

A very slight variation from [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10766107/4621141), [Henry Wrightson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17421508/4621141) and [Rafael Rocha](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14206385/4621141) answers:

```js
var foo = (() => {

  // Paste in your original object
  const foo = {
    a: 5,
    b: 6,
  };
  
  // Use their properties
  foo.c = foo.a + foo.b;

  // Do whatever else you want

  // Finally, return object
  return foo;
})();

console.log(foo);
```

The slight advantage here is just pasting your original object as it was, without worrying about arguments etc. (IMHO the wrapper function becomes quite transparent this way).

#### Second: using setTimeout

This here may work, if you don't need `foo.c` right away:

```js
var foo = {
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
  c: setTimeout(() => foo.c = foo.a + foo.b, 0)
};

// Though, at first, foo.c will be the integer returned by setTimeout
console.log(foo);
// But if this isn't an issue, the value will be updated when time comes in the event loop
setTimeout( () => console.log(foo), 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I came up with another solution. Here I want to initialize an object representing the amount of milliseconds for each unit of time.
It turns out enum in typescript can not be used in my case, so I declared multiple variables that I assign to an object as follow:

```js
const SECOND = 1000
const MINUTE = 60 * SECOND
const HOUR = 60 * MINUTE
const DAY = 24 * HOUR
const WEEK = 7 * DAY

export const TimeInMS = {
  SECOND,
  MINUTE,
  HOUR,
  DAY,
  WEEK
}
```

The drawbacks of this method are:

- variables are defined as constants, even if we dont need them. Thus it needs useless memory.
- each value of the object must be declared as standalone variable

Answer (score 0):

Although an object declaration does not allow you to reference prior properties, the default values in a function declaration do.

Therefore, you can do this:

```js
const foo = ((a=5, b=6, c=a+b) => ({a,b,c}))()

console.log(foo)
```

Answer (score -1):

> **Note:** This solution uses Typescript (you can use the vanilla JS which TS compiles to if needed)

```
class asd {
    def = new class {
        ads= 'asd';
        qwe= this.ads + '123';
    };
    
    // this method is just to check/test this solution 
    check(){
        console.log(this.def.qwe);
    }
}

// these two lines are just to check
let instance = new asd();
instance.check();
```

Here were using class expressions to get the nested object literal interface we'd want. This is the next best thing IMHO to being able to reference the properties of an object during creation.

Main thing to note is while using this solution, you have exact same interface as you'd have had from an object literal. And the syntax is pretty close to an object literal itself (vs using a function, etc).

### Compare the following

#### Solution I've proposed

```
class asd {
    def = new class {
        ads= 'asd';
        qwe= this.ads + '123';
    };
```

#### Solution if object literals would've sufficed

```
var asd = {
    def : {
        ads:'asd',
        qwe: this.ads + '123';, //ILLEGAL CODE; just to show ideal scenario
    }
}
```

### Another example

Here in this class, you can combine multiple relative path among themselves, which is not possible with an object literal.

```typescript
class CONSTANT {
    static readonly PATH = new class {
        /** private visibility because these relative paths don't make sense for direct access, they're only useful to path class
         *
         */
        private readonly RELATIVE = new class {
            readonly AFTER_EFFECTS_TEMPLATE_BINARY_VERSION: fs.PathLike = '\\assets\\aep-template\\src\\video-template.aep';
            readonly AFTER_EFFECTS_TEMPLATE_XML_VERSION: fs.PathLike = '\\assets\\aep-template\\intermediates\\video-template.aepx';
            readonly RELATIVE_PATH_TO_AFTER_EFFECTS: fs.PathLike = '\\Adobe\\Adobe After Effects CC 2018\\Support Files\\AfterFX.exe';
            readonly OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_NAME: fs.PathLike = '\\output';
            readonly INPUT_DIRECTORY_NAME: fs.PathLike = '\\input';
            readonly ASSETS_DIRECTORY_NAME: fs.PathLike = '\\assets';
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Could it be because your answer is totally irrelevant? I agree that downvoters should explain, but your answer clear has nothing to do with the question …

Comment: @Manngo thanks for pointing it out. Honestly, I'd the same question as OP and I use solution I've suggested. Unsure, why it's being considered irrelevant. If you do have the time, please explain so I can make the answer better or at least know where I'm wrong. I'm unfortunately, not understanding why this is not a reasonable solution.

Comment: This doesn't address the problem of self reference at all. What you proposed is a rather convoluted way of emulating self reference by introducing unnecessary closure in your code.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use native JS, the other answers provide good solutions.

But if you're willing to write self-referencing objects like:

```
{ 
  a: ...,
  b: "${this.a + this.a}",
}
```

I wrote an npm library called [self-referenced-object](https://github.com/alex-e-leon/self-referenced-object) that supports that syntax and returns a native object.

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Quentin do you have any suggestions on how I can improve my answer?

The other answers to this question cover how you might be able to write self-referencing objects in native javascript, but if you want to write self-referencing objects with a syntax similar to the syntax in the posters original question I think that the library that I wrote may be useful to others looking for a solution.

Happy to get some feedback.

Comment: Couple things to improve here. First, and most obviously, you're using template literal syntax without back ticks. Your `b` property's value should be: ``${this.a + this.a}``. Second, but less importantly, you'd want to return a number, not a string by using something like `parseInt`. Last and MOST importantly, when I tried this example it simply doesn't work, for the same reason the OP is asking. The `this` returns undefined when used its own object declaration. @alex-e-leon

Comment: @AlecDonaldMather - thanks for taking the time to take a look and provide some feedback! If you're interested in the project it might be better to move this discussion over to github, but to answer some of your feedback:
- Using backticks: As mentioned in previous comments, this syntax isnt supported by JS, and so using strings instead of backticks is required here to avoid js trying to resolve "this" before the obj has been defined
- returning a number, this should work if a + b are already numbers, since a + b will return a number if both a and b are already numbers.

Comment: Re this returning undefined, can you explain how you tried to use the library? This shouldn't happen, but maybe there's an edge case I've left out? That said, this library doesn't solve the issue completely, and has it's own set of tradeoffs, but if you're interested in helping me to improve it/use it let me know!

Answer (score -1):

Other approach would be to declare the object first before assigning properties into it:

```
const foo = {};
foo.a = 5;
foo.b = 6;
foo.c = foo.a + foo.b;  // Does work
foo.getSum = () => foo.a + foo.b + foo.c;  // foo.getSum() === 22
```

With that, you can use the object variable name to access the already assigned values.
Best for `config.js` file.

Comment: That isn't a self reference, but rather a reference to the declared variable `foo` which points to the object in question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to avoid using the `this` keyword, you can use my ES6 approach below

```js
const MEASUREMENT = {
  device_width: 124,
  canvas_padding: 24,
  full_width: () => MEASUREMENT.device_width - MEASUREMENT.canvas_padding,
};
```

Answer (score -4):

```
var x = {
    a: (window.secreta = 5),
    b: (window.secretb = 6),
    c: window.secreta + window.secretb
};
```

This is almost identical to @slicedtoad's answer, but doesn't use a function.